# bootstrap padding not as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

html

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-9 column">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="a">
            <p>One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than 
    he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date. 
    However, I didn’t have a girlfriend. One of my other friends, who had a date to go to the party with, asked me about my date. 
    I didn’t want to be embarrassed, so I claimed that I had a lot of work to do. I said I could easily find a date even better than his if I wanted
    to. I also told him that his date was ugly. I achieved power to help me feel confident; however, I embarrassed my friend and his date. Although
    this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself</p>
            </div>
            <div class="a">
            <p>One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than 
    he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date. 
    However, I didn’t have a girlfriend. One of my other friends, who had a date to go to the party with, asked me about my date. 
    I didn’t want to be embarrassed, so I claimed that I had a lot of work to do. I said I could easily find a date even better than his if I wanted
    to. I also told him that his date was ugly. I achieved power to help me feel confident; however, I embarrassed my friend and his date. Although
    this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="col-md-3 column">
    <p>One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than 
    he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date. 
    However, I didn’t have a girlfriend. One of my other friends, who had a date to go to the party with, asked me about my date. 
    I didn’t want to be embarrassed, so I claimed that I had a lot of work to do. I said I could   easily find a date even better than his if I wanted
    to. I also told him that his date was ugly. I achieved power to help me feel confident;      however, I embarrassed my friend and his date. Although
    this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.a{
padding:10px;
background-color:pink;
margin-bottom:10px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #B2B2B2;
}
#b{
padding:20px;
background-color:yellow;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #B2B2B2;
}
```

when i used padding the gaps are hidden between the a classes and how to give a space between a's and b so that their will be white space between all

http://www.bootply.com/gIOn5aMXx6

Comment: <div class="a"> and <div class="b"> should be columns, for example: <div class="a col-md-6"> and <div class="b col-md-6">

Comment: can u provide a bootply pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed a "wrapper" to go around your 'a' classes:

```
<div class="aWrapper">
    <div class="a">
        <p>One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than 
    he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date. 
    However, I didn’t have a girlfriend. One of my other friends, who had a date to go to the party with, asked me about my date. 
    I didn’t want to be embarrassed, so I claimed that I had a lot of work to do. I said I could easily find a date even better than his if I wanted
    to. I also told him that his date was ugly. I achieved power to help me feel confident; however, I embarrassed my friend and his date. Although
    this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <p>One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than 
    he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date. 
    However, I didn’t have a girlfriend. One of my other friends, who had a date to go to the party with, asked me about my date. 
    I didn’t want to be embarrassed, so I claimed that I had a lot of work to do. I said I could easily find a date even better than his if I wanted
    to. I also told him that his date was ugly. I achieved power to help me feel confident; however, I embarrassed my friend and his date. Although
    this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example:
http://www.bootply.com/8TwSbK8Awn

Answer (score 0):

The div class="row clearfix" wrapping the "a" needs to have a width, like 100%; I used that and it shows the gap now.

Comment: yeah..but gap between a and b?

Answer (score 0):

Add .col-md-12 after a in both cases

```
<div class="a col-md-12">
```